# Rails sum returns wrong value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

###### Environment

ruby: 3.1.2p20

rails: 7.0.7.2

###### Steps to reproduce

```
TestModel.create(id: 0, value: 10.0)
TestModel.create(id: 1, value: 10.0)

TestModel.where(id: [0,1]).distinct.sum(:value)
```

###### Expected outcome

20.0

###### Actual outcome

10.0

Why is the calculation incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour lies in the generated SQL query which is

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT "test_models"."value") FROM "test_models" WHERE "test_models"."id" IN ($1, $2)  [["id", 0], ["id", 1]]
```

It calls **distinct** on the values instead on the objects and therefore eliminates the duplicates which results in the unexpected sum.

Is this a bug or a feature? Hard to tell, there is a [issue for rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33082) which was closed, meaning this behaviour will not change.

To "fix" the sum you can select all values and sum the execution of the values like this

```
TestModel.where(id: [0,1]).distinct.map(&:value).sum
```

Comment: I'd say its a feature. Rails is still building the query at that point. I'd just remove the distinct and let MySql do the work.

Comment: definitely a feature. you don't need distinct here

Answer (score 0):

`distinct` works such probably unexpected way

To achieve the final goal, you can use the following options

Sum with Ruby

```rb
TestModel.where(id: [0, 1]).distinct.sum(&:value)
# SELECT DISTINCT * FROM test_models WHERE id IN (0, 1);
```

Sum with RDBMS

```rb
TestModel.select(:value).from(TestModel.where(id: [0, 1]).distinct).sum(:value)
# SELECT SUM(value) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM test_models WHERE id IN (0, 1));
```